# Adding social share buttons and making them work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create social icons with the php-theme files and CSS. I have managed to create a few social icons using some code. They are now located at the top of the post before the headline and text begins, in the post below.

But they don't go anywhere when readers click them.

I am basing what I am doing on this article: https://www.w3schools.com/howt/howto_css_social_media_buttons.asp

I added this code in php and CSS:

In the file editor I added this code:

```
<!-- Add icon library --><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><!-- Add font awesome icons --><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a><a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
```

In CSS I added this code:

```
/* Style all font awesome icons */
.fa {padding: 10px;
font-size: 30px;
width: 35px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}
/* Add a hover effect if you want */
.fa:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}
/* Set a specific color for each brand */
/* Facebook */
.fa-facebook {
background: #3B5998;
color: white;
}
/* Twitter */
.fa-twitter {
background: #55ACEE;
color: white;
}
/* Pinterest */
.fa-pinterest {
background: #cb2027;
color: white;
}
```

Now, something happens when you hover these icons. A little color is blinking when hovering. But they don't go anywhere when you press them with the arrow.

Also, how can I make them have “share” and “like” attributes as roll downs? I want it to appear two alternatives when you hover Facebook: "share" and "like". It should be two alternatives. Right now when readers click them they are not directed to these platforms(facebook, pinterest and twitter) at all. It is not even an automatical like, share or tweet-alternative when they hover or click it.

Is it possible to make it so that when readers hover the symbol, a scroll down list appears for facebook with two alternatives: Either “like” or “share”.

And for the twitter button: Either “tweet” or “follow”
For Pinterest: “Pin it”.

The article I am using them in is this one(above the headline are three symbols that are not clickable):
https://valuetrendsblog.com/2020/01/why-amazon-could-soar/

Comment: You need to provide a URL to make those buttons work. Copy the link to your facebook page and paste it where the "#" is. Like <a href="https://www.facebook.com/yourpage" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>

Comment: Hmm ok. But I want to create a scroll down that appears when you hover the icon. So two alternatives appear: "like" and "share" so that the reader gets two alternatives. Not just a send button, if you know what I mean?